# For each country/colour/brand combination , find sum of number of items in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

This is a portion of the data I have indexed in elasticsearch:

```
{
  "country" : "India",
  "colour" : "white",
  "brand" : "sony"
  "numberOfItems" : 3
}
```

I want to get the total sum of `numberOfItems` on a per country basis, per colour basis and per brand basis. Is there any way to do this in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 2):

The following should land you straight to the answer.
Make sure you enable scripting before using it.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "keys": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "doc['country'].value + doc['color'].value + doc['brand'].value"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "keySum": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "numberOfItems"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a single result you may use [sum aggregation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html) applied to a filtered query with term (terms) filter, e.g.:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "country": "India"
                } 
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "total_sum": {
            "sum": {
                "field": "numberOfItems"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To get statistics for all countries/colours/brands in a single pass over the data you may use the following query with 3 multi-bucket aggregations, each of them containing a single-bucket sum [sub-aggregation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/_buckets_inside_buckets.html):

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "aggs": {
        "countries": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "country"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "country_sum": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "numberOfItems"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "colours": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "colour"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "colour_sum": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "numberOfItems"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "brands": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "brand"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "brand_sum": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "numberOfItems"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```